# Dimension of affine varieties preserves for open subsets

Tags: algebraic-geometry, zariski-topology

**My problem:** Let $X$ be an affine variety and $U$ an open subset of $X$. Then $dim U = dim X$.

**My attempt:** If I take a chain of irreducible and closed sets $Z_1\subsetneq... \subsetneq Z_n$ in $U$, then I get a chain of irreducible and closed sets $\bar Z_1\subsetneq ... \subsetneq \bar Z_n$.

I'd like to prove that if the chain in $U$ is a non-refinable chain of irreducible and closed sets, then the chain of its clausures is a non-refinable chain of irreducible and closed sets on $X$. Then, I'd like to build some chain of prime ideal using the fact $I(Z_0)$ maximal and finding that $n$ is the hight.

However. I don't know how can I avance and prove this...

Comment: [Potential duplicate #1 if you know about schemes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1789033/dimension-of-irreducible-affine-variety-is-same-as-any-open-subset), or [potential duplicate #2 if you know that the dimension is the transcendence degree of the function field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1289355/a-zariski-open-subset-of-a-variety-has-the-same-dimension-as-the-variety).

Comment: Do you know to prove the next? : if the chain in $U$ is a non-refinable chain of irreducible and closed sets, then the chain of its clausures is a non-refinable chain of irreducible and closed sets on $X$.

Comment: If that's the only method of solution you're interested in, I would recommend making an [edit] to your post so that's made clear. (You could also clean up a couple of minor issues - spellcheck, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

To show the equality of dimensions, it suffices to show that $Z \mapsto \overline{Z}$ and $Z \mapsto Z \cap U$ gives an order preserving bijection between the irreducible closed subsets of $U$ and the irreducible closed subsets of $X$ which intersect $U$. This follows from the definition of irreducibility.

Comment: A proof of this statment can be found here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1021297/why-are-the-irreducible-components-of-a-subspace-of-noetherian-space-just-the-in